# Makefile error - make: *** No rule to make target `boot.o', needed by `all'. Stop

Tags: makefile, kernel, yasm

I am working through a unix-like kernel development tutorial, and have come across a total noob problem I am sure:  can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

```
SOURCES=boot.o main.o

CFLAGS=-nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector
LDFLAGS=-Tlink.ld
ASFLAGS=-felf

all: $(SOURCES) link 

clean:
    -rm *.o kernel

link:
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o kernel $(SOURCES)

.s.o:
    yasm $(ASFLAGS) $
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked if boot.o file exists?

Comment: @SidR, no it can't find a **rule** to compile it

Comment: @aleguna True. But if you have the boot.o file already, you don't need to compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [old-fashioned suffix rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules), and missing some setup for that (plus an error in the very last line).

Switch to a normal pattern rule instead, no point in trying to fix the old style rule:

```
%.o: %.s
    yasm $(ASFLAGS) $<
```

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming `boot.o` and  `main.o` are built using `yasm` your makefile lack a rule for `.o`

```
.o:
    yasm $(ASFLAGS) $
```